# Vlc raspian mono c# windows form

Tags: c#, windows, mono, vlc

Hi try vlc viewr un c# windows form project.

When I reproduce video it work on windows, but it doesnt' work on raspian.

Code is this:

```
 LibVLCSharp.Shared.LibVLC libVLC = new LibVLC();
                    Media media = new Media(libVLC, new Uri(this.localVideoPath + _url));

                    
                    videoView1.MediaPlayer = new LibVLCSharp.Shared.MediaPlayer(media);
                    videoView1.MediaPlayer.Mute = true;

                    bool result = videoView1.MediaPlayer.Play(new Media(libVLC, this.localVideoPath + _url, FromType.FromPath));//.FromLocation));
                    LoggerManagerUtility.Instance.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Info, this, "Play result " + result.ToString());
```

Error is the following:

```
[02786420] main video output error: video output creation failed
[7037e590] main decoder error: failed to create video output
[h264 @ 0x703e7880] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x703e7880] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x703e7880] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x703e7880] no frame!
```

But if i try to see the same video on raspian whit vlc it work?

Can you help me?

Comment: You posted several questions and wished to port a typical WinForms app with multiple native Windows dependencies to Mono and a non-Windows OS. That's doomed to fail, so please stop wasting your own time (as well as others').

Comment: this sample isn't complete, but yeah, if you're using WinForms on Linux, don't.